# iPhone SDK - How to draw a UIImage onto another UIImage?

Tags: iphone, drawing, uiimage

I have several rectangular images (in landscape and portrait mode) and want to draw them onto  a transparent square image, so that all images became the same size without cropping them. How would I create a transparent UIImage and draw another on top?

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Create a bitmap graphic context with `CGBitmapContextCreate`. You'll need to determine what the size of the resulting composite image here. You can think of this as a sort of canvas.
2. Draw the images using `CGContextDrawImage`. This will draw images onto the same context.
3. Once you're done drawing all the images into the same context, create an image from that context with `CGBitmapContextCreateImage`.
4. Convert the Core Graphics image from step #3 into a UIImage with `[UIImage imageWithCGIImage:]`.

Code examples can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH203-CJBHBFFE).