# Need some assistance in overlaying a UIImage onto another UIImage?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an application where a user is able to annotate a signature image on top of a fax image (tif) before sending out the fax. I have seen a very good question mentioned here: [iPhone SDK - How to draw a UIImage onto another UIImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349007/iphone-sdk-how-to-draw-a-uiimage-onto-another-uiimage) however I still am unable to do what I am looking for. Can someone walk me through as I am new to graphical contexts ETC.

Comment: Can you perhaps let us know what you've tried and what the results were?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you need to do to get the image,

```
CGRect faxImageRect = CGRectZero;
CGRect signatureRect = CGRectZero;

faxImageRect.size = faxImage.size;
signatureRect.size = signature.size;

// Adjust the signature's location within the fax image
signatureRect.origin = desirableLocation;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(faxImage.size);
[faxImage drawInRect:faxImageRect];
[signature drawInRect:signatureRect];
image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

By the end `image` will contain the image you want to send.

This sample uses the true sizes of their images. You can alter that although they could be subject to stretching.

Comment: I will try this and let you know. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can suggest a workaround. :)
Actually, because the iOS is working with views you can create yourself 2 UIImageViews and add one as a subview of the other.
If you are interested in the lower level drawing stuff just read
[Quartz 2D](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: good suggestion however I do need to save the final UiImage and then transmit it.